# How can I use Mutate with ifelse to parse string data into a new variable?

Tags: r, string, if-statement, dplyr, stringr

I'm newer to R and am playing around with the Titanic kaggle dataset. I've watched David Langer's great youtube videos on exploring this dataset and he is able to parse out the titles of each passenger with a for loop. However, I can't help but figure there is an easier way to do this with mutate and stringr.

note: titanic.full = data.frame

This is my best guess... obviously it doesn't work though:

```
mutate(titanic.full, Title = ifelse(str_detect(titanic.full$Name, "Mr."), "Mr.") elseif(str_detect(titanic.full$Name, "Mrs."), "Mrs."), "Other")
```

Any guidance would be very appreciated.

Comment: Nest `ifelse`. `ifelse(str_detect(Name, "Mr."), "Mr.", ifelse(str_detect(Name, "Mrs."), "Mrs.", "Other"))`

Comment: `case_when` is your friend here

Comment: So I tried the following:  mutate(titanic.full, Title = ifelse(str_detect(Name, "Mr."), "Mr.", ifelse(str_detect(Name, "Mrs."), "Mrs.", "Other"))  but this didn't seem to work as an unexpected symbol error came up

Answer (score 1):

Using a regular expression match seems easier here.   `.*?` matches all characters up to the first occurrence of what follows.  `(Mr|Mrs|Miss|$)` matches any of the options with `$` meaning end of line (in order to capture any lines that have none of the prior values).  Finally `.*` matches whatever is left.  `"\\1"` refers to the characters that match the portion of the pattern within parentheses.

```
titanic.full %>% mutate(Title = sub(".*?(Mr|Mrs|Miss|$).*", "\\1", Name))
```

**Note:**  Since the input was not provided reproducibly in the question we provide it here:

```
u <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vincentarelbundock/Rdatasets/master/csv/datasets/Titanic.csv"
titanic.full <- read.csv(u)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It appears my attempts at avoiding metacharacters needs to end. I plugged this in and it worked! Now to search and read up on metacharacter so I can apply this!

Comment: I see that. Thanks so much!

Comment: I've read up on my regular expressions and found an even more convenient way to capture all titles unknown that I didn't include before:           
    titanic.full <- titanic.full %>% 
  mutate(AllTitles = sub(".*?,(.+\\.).*", "\\1", Name))

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `tidyverse` solution you can do the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vincentarelbundock/Rdatasets/master/csv/datasets/Titanic.csv"
df <- read.csv(df, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df <- as_tibble(df)
df

df %>% 
  extract(Name, 
          "Title",
          "(Mr|Mrs|Miss) ([^ ]+)", 
          remove = FALSE) %>% 
  select(Name, Title)
```

Which returns:

```
# A tibble: 1,313 x 2
                                            Name Title
 *                                         <chr> <chr>
 1                  Allen, Miss Elisabeth Walton  Miss
 2                   Allison, Miss Helen Loraine  Miss
 3           Allison, Mr Hudson Joshua Creighton    Mr
 4 Allison, Mrs Hudson JC (Bessie Waldo Daniels)   Mrs
 5                 Allison, Master Hudson Trevor  <NA>
 6                            Anderson, Mr Harry    Mr
 7              Andrews, Miss Kornelia Theodosia  Miss
 8                        Andrews, Mr Thomas, jr    Mr
 9  Appleton, Mrs Edward Dale (Charlotte Lamson)   Mrs
10                        Artagaveytia, Mr Ramon    Mr
# ... with 1,303 more rows
```

Thanks to **G. Grothendieck** for providing the data.